# Ubuntu sudo required for listening on port 80 but not on other unused ports

Tags: ubuntu, http

On my Ubuntu desktop, I'm able to successfully run a small C++ webserver on **unused ports** like this:

```
./myserver 127.0.0.1 3050
```

This problem is that if I run on port 80, I must run as **sudo** like this:

```
sudo ./myserver 127.0.0.1 80
```

If I run on **port 80 without using sudo**, I get an error **accept: Invalid argument**.

Can someone explain why sudo is required when running on port 80?

Comment: Because port 80 is *privileged* and you must have a privilege to bind to it. `sudo` grants you such privilege; it can also be other way, by setting Linux capabilities. However, this question belongs to the SuperUser, and even there it'll be ill-received, because it is *very basic*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The TCP/IP port numbers below 1024 are special in that normal users are not allowed to run servers on them. This is a security feature, in that if you connect to a service on one of these ports you can be fairly sure that you have the real thing, and not a fake which some hacker has put up for you.

Above is from: 
https://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html
Also, check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_port

Comment: Thank you very much, this was driving me nuts!